# How to navigate to a certain type

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, navigation

I am looking for a way to navigate straight to a certain *type* of Go in VSCode. Specifically,  a shortcut equivalent to :

- CTRL+SHIFT+N in Intellij
- CTRL+SHIFT+T in Eclipse

... both for Java code.

(When I say "straight to..." I mean from anywhere you are in VSCode, and not being already on a given type in code editor and use hover shortcuts - like F12. sure that one works fine)

I have already browsed... some links are talking about shortcut CTRL+T : but it does not the job as waited.
For instance i tried to navigate to type "Scanner" - which is in bufio/scan.go - but CTRL+T does not lead to this type in GO file.

Have you any workaround?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported by the VSCode Go plugin.

Comment: Too bad... ok, ICZA, thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

Assuming VSCode has indexed your project and you have the `ms-vscode.go` plugin installed, you can use the "Go to Symbol in Workspace" feature to navigate to types and functions in your workspace. Read more in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name).

As you mentioned, this does **not** find types outside of your workspace.

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or find "Go to Symbol in Workspace" under the "Go" menu.

[image]